# Project is not Updating to the Changes in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, development-environment

I recently added a `Button` in my layout.The `Button` is showing in the preview. But when i run my project it doesn't shows the changes and the `Button`.But I can assure the project is running & showing details in the LOG. I tried to generate a signed APK and installed it. It also results the same.

The connect layout has the Button and the changes.

```
public class connect extends Activity{
WifiApManager wifiApManager;
TextView tv;
Button scan;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connect);
    tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.iptv);
    wifiApManager = new WifiApManager(this);
    scan=(Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);
    scan();
    scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            scan();
        }
    });
}


    private void scan() {
    ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients = wifiApManager.getClientList(false);
    tv.setText("WifiApState: " + wifiApManager.getWifiApState() + "\n\n");
    tv.append("Clients: \n");
    for (ClientScanResult clientScanResult : clients) {
        tv.append("####################\n");
        tv.append("IpAddr: " + clientScanResult.getIpAddr() + "\n");
        tv.append("Device: " + clientScanResult.getDevice() + "\n");
        tv.append("HWAddr: " + clientScanResult.getHWAddr() + "\n");
        tv.append("isReachable: " + clientScanResult.isReachable() + "\n");
    }
}
}
```

Already Tried :

1.Cleaned Project

2.File -> Invalidate Caches

3.Rebuild Project

4.Restarted IDE

Thanks for your Help.

Comment: please post your activity class.